# Numbers place...the output is wrong from code

Tags: text, numbers, digits

this is my code:

```
<i class="fa fa-credit-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>(or any other font icons) 123 myText
```

the problem is here:
the font-icon will come between text and digits. the output is:
**123 (icon) myText**

Help me please... thanks.

Comment: Is that how the output *is*, or what you want it to be? Is "myText" by any chance written in a right-to-left language (Arabic, Hebrew...)?

Comment: Yes its RTL, I write a code for: (ICON) 123MyText but the output is 123 (ICON) MyText

Answer (score 0):

**I found the problem , in fa class in css there is a display: inline; , this line is the problem, But yet , idk how to change this for all FA classes**